# Powershell - running a ps1 script on all ps1 files in a directory

Tags: powershell

I have about 50 ps1 scripts on a local server directory - E:/scripts/. These have different functions for collecting server / application stats etc.

**Updated to add more info about script**
There is a second ps1 script - a.ps1, which I am trying to run using powershell. This a.ps1 has a function defined - **fn-run** - and after doing a `Import-Module a.ps1`, it is used with the following syntax:

```
fn-run <stats collector script name> servername domainname
for example:
fn-run E:/scripts/script1.ps1 myserver localdomain
```

I am able to gather list of script files using powershell like this:

```
$i = 0    
$allscripts = Get-ChildItem E:/scripts/ | where {$_.extension -eq ".ps1"} | % {
         Write-Host $_.FullName
    }

foreach ($script in $allscripts) {
    $script,
    $i++
    }
```

This gives a full list of script files in E:/scripts/ directory. Now, I am trying to figure out how to pass these to **a.ps1**..?

Thanks..

Comment: what do you mean by "pass"?

Comment: What is `fn-run;`? Do you mean you want to run `a.ps1 e:\path\to\script.ps1 servername domainname` for every ps1-file you find? `$allscripts` won't contain anything because you use `Write-Host` which only writes to the console, remove it..

Comment: @FrodeF. Yes, that is correct. Run `a.ps1 e:\path\to\script.ps1 servername domainname` is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Okey, because your question says something completely different (and is also unclear). See if the answer I posted helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
Import-Module a.ps1

$allscripts = Get-ChildItem -Path  E:/scripts/ -Filter "*.ps1" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

foreach ($script in $allscripts) {
    fn-run $script myserver localdomain
}
```

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear. I have just started with powershell. I updated the question with some more info. a.ps1 has a function define - fn-run. To use the script, I first run a `'Import-Module a.ps1'`. Then, I use - `fn-run e:\scripts\script.ps1 myserver localdomain`. Does it help clarify..?

Comment: With the answer you have shared, I think, there has to be an Import-Module for a.ps1 first before passing the arguments to it..

Comment: See updated answer. What is `myserver` and `localdomain`? Static values or should it be the name and domain for the computer you're running this on?

Comment: These 2 are static values, and can vary only slightly. The updated script works perfectly! Thanks.